# sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) vs. CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Tags: c, linux, time, process, clock

I was wondering what is the difference between the return value of the aforementioned constants.

`sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` returns `100` 
`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` returns `1,000,000`

So, suppose that I have this:

```
...
start = clock();
// Process starts here 
/* does something */
// Process ends here
end = clock();
double time = ((double) end-start)/CLOCK_PER_SEC; // this would return in seconds
...
```

How do I calculate the amount of ticks used by the process, instead of the time? Do I use time used against `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` or `CLOCK_PER_SEC`?

I am trying to understand the usage of those.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `clock()` returns the "number of ticks" whose rate is given by `CLOCK_PER_SEC`.

Comment: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` does not *return* anything, it is a value defined for the preprocessor. Whereas `sysconf` is a non-standard *function* that returns information about the OS it is running on.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is standard in POSIX. Not in C, true.

Comment: Don't use `clock()`. Use `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`, `#include <time.h>`, and [`clock_gettime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html). Having `struct timespec ts;`, call `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts);` and you'll have the time spent by the CPU to run this process in `ts.tv_sec` in seconds plus nanoseconds (0 to 999,999,999) in `ts.tv_nsec`. Use `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` for the CPU time spent by current thread, and `CLOCK_REALTIME` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for wall clock. (Both are immune to DST changes etc., the latter even against manual changes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, `clock()` returns time in resolution of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Other time functions return values with resolution in *ticks*. `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` provides the number of ticks per second. One such time function is `times()`.

Comment: So, let's say that in `time = ((double) end-start` without the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, this would measure the time in microseconds right? Does it necessary to divide of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to actually get it in seconds, or is it okay to just divide it off 1,000,000 to get it in seconds? I mean, they both have the same value. So I am not too sure.

To get the number of ticks, I would just have `int ticks = time * sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK`, right?

Comment: As mentioned in comments, there are less troublesome functions you can use. But, stick to documented interfaces. Although unlikely, the definition of CLOCKS_PER_SEC may change.