# Does `clock` measure `sleep` i.e. suspended threads?

Tags: c, sleep, clock

I am trying to understand the `clock_t clock(void);` function better and have following question:

Did I understand that correctly that `clock` measures the number of ticks of a process since it is **actively running** and `sleep` suspends the calling thread – in this case there is only one thread, namely the main-thread – and therefore suspends the whole process. Which means that `clock` does not measure the cpu-time (ticks) of the process, since it is not actively running?
If so what is the recommended way to measure the actual needed time?

"The `clock()` function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program." [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock)
"The CPU time (process time) is measured in clock ticks or seconds." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time)
"The number of clock ticks per second can be obtained using: `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);`" [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/2/times)

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <time.h>   // clock
#include <unistd.h> // sleep

int main()
{
  printf("ticks per second: %zu\n", sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK));

  clock_t ticks_since_process_startup_1 = clock();
  sleep(1);
  clock_t ticks_since_process_startup_2 = clock();

  printf("ticks_probe_1:    %zu\n", ticks_since_process_startup_1);
  printf("sleep(1);\n");
  printf("ticks_probe_2:    %zu\n", ticks_since_process_startup_2);
  printf("ticks diff:       %zu <-- should be 100\n", ticks_since_process_startup_2 - ticks_since_process_startup_1);
  printf("ticks diff sec:   %Lf <-- should be 1 second\n", (long double)(ticks_since_process_startup_2 - ticks_since_process_startup_1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

**Resulting Output:**

```
ticks per second: 100
ticks_probe_1:    603
sleep(1);
ticks_probe_2:    616
ticks diff:       13 <-- should be 100
ticks diff sec:   0.000013 <-- should be 1 second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `clock` measure `sleep` i.e. suspended threads?

No.

(Well, it could measure it, there's nothing against it. You could have a very bad OS that implements `sleep()` as a `while (!time_to_sleep_expired()) {}` busy loop. But any self-respected OS will try to make the process not to use CPU when in `sleep()`).

> Which means that clock does not measure the cpu-time (ticks) of the process, since it is not actively running?

Yes.

> If so what is the recommended way to measure the actual needed time?

To measure "real-time" use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` on a POSIX system.

> The number of clock ticks per second can be obtained using: sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

Yes, but note that `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);` **is not** `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND`. You do not use ex `times()` in your function, you use `clock()`, I do not really get why you print `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);`. Anyway, see for example [sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) vs. CLOCKS_PER_SEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712808/sysconf-sc-clk-tck-vs-clocks-per-sec) .